# Laravel 5.2 can't set offset $request->page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having trouble creating a custom pagination.

If I do this, it does not work:

```
$page = json_decode($request->page);
// $page = 5;
$offset = $page * $limit - $limit;

$query->offset($offset);
$query->limit($limit);
```

If i do this, it works:

```
// $page = json_decode($request->page);
$page = 5;
$offset = $page * $limit - $limit;

$query->offset($offset);
$query->limit($limit);
```

When I `var_dump`, I can see both `$page` values are `int`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does this code outputs `dd(json_decode($request->page));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it just outputs a clean 2 - which is my page number. 

Output: 
https://gyazo.com/e843248ed47b5a6230fdb806eaca90f9

Page set in URL:
https://gyazo.com/08b5f04e44b305c06cabd044a2d89d67

Comment: Try to change to this `$page = (int)json_decode($request->page);` Also, when you're saying it doesn't work, what does it mean? Do you get any error or something?

Comment: Same result. :-) 

Sorry, It means that, it gets all my products, but the offset is ignored. It is not ignored if i just put af 5.

Comment: what shows dd($offset . ' - ' . $limit); ? (In the first not working example)

Comment: well. this request works. But it seems that you are sending another request, it is going to be conflicted. The conflict starts when you send another request. first request is 2, the second one is null.

Comment: @Eimantas Gabrielius: 
It shows:
"5 - 5"
When page is 2, and so on. :-)

Comment: @Rashad, im not sure i follow. How do you mean 2 requests? :-)

Comment: Provide your full controller

Comment: @RK4002 so, I see here that page = 2, limit = 5, so offset = 2 * 5 - 5 = 5. Main logic is kind of working. Cant you use paginate() ? And show full controller code please.

Comment: @Rashad: 

https://gist.github.com/rk4002/0445de5b4e5e627968ae690b181df7a6

Comment: @Eimantas Gabrielius: 

I very much would love to, but it's the same thing, so i would just create my own i thought. :D

Comment: Did you try to return `$request->page` ? if `dd($request->page)` shows 2. I understand it. try just to return `$request->page`